# How to remap topic in a ROS2 launch file?

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am setting up a navigation2 launch file.

I have used [this one](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/foxy-devel/nav2_bringup/bringup/launch/tb3_simulation_launch.py) as a reference, and everything seems to work.

However, I need to remap the `/cmd_vel` topic. I am not sure what is the syntax to do so in a top-level launch file to have it propagated to a nested launch file.

Thanks for the help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376720/how-to-remap-topic-in-a-ros2-launch-file?/) by [g.bardaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/28875/g.bardaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2021-04-22

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found an example on the ros2 tutorials (Foxy)

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Launch-file-different-formats.html

> ## perform remap so both turtles listen to the same command topic

```
forward_turtlesim_commands_to_second_turtlesim_node = Node(
        package='turtlesim',
        executable='mimic',
        name='mimic',
        remappings=[
            ('/input/pose', '/turtlesim1/turtle1/pose'),
            ('/output/cmd_vel', '/turtlesim2/turtle1/cmd_vel'),
        ]
    )
```

---

Originally posted by [Richard Mark Haes Ellis](https://answers.ros.org/users/76692/richard-mark-haes-ellis/) with karma: 56 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K88](https://answers.ros.org/users/120644/k88/) on 2022-10-19**:
Invaluable for remapping RVIZ' /initial_pose, /goal_pose, and /clicked_point topics (connected to 2D Pose Estimate, 2d Goal Pose, and Publish Point buttons in RVIZ) that are otherwise permanently outside any namespace applied to an RVIZ node. Thank you!